# ¿Cómo enviar date time de cada dato obtenido en arduino a python?

Tags: python, datetime, arduino, pyserial

tengo un código sencillo en arduino que corresponde a un contador hasta 10 que luego se reinicia a 1 y quisiera enviar el **date time** de cada uno de esos valores del contador (los cuales ya están siendo enviados a python y registrándose en una lista).

Este es el código de arduino:

```
int cont=0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  cont++;
  Serial.print(cont);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println();
  if(cont >= 10){
    cont=0;
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

Y a continuación, el código en python que registra los valores de los contadores:

```
import sys, time, serial

time.sleep(3)             # Generar un retardo 3ms
numPoints = 100            # Cantidad de datos
dataList = [0]*numPoints


# Obtención de los datos:
with serial.Serial('COM6',9600) as ser:
    def getValues():
        ser.write(b'g')
        arduinoData = ser.readline().decode('ascii','ignore')
        arduinoData_2 = arduinoData.strip(',\r\n')

        return arduinoData_2


    for i in range(0,numPoints):
        data = getValues()
        #guarda en vector datalist:
        dataList[i] = int(data)

print(dataList)
```

Si pudieran ayudarme con la obtención del **data time** de cada dato registrado, por favor

Comment: El Arduino no tiene reloj de tiempo real. Si necesitas obtner la fecha y hora, puedes usar un RTC externo, como el DS3231, que se conecta vía I2C.

Comment: @CandidMoe, en ese caso, es posible obtener la fecha y hora con python?

Comment: Correcto. Puedes poner la hora/fecha en el PC, al recibir el dato.

Comment: Si coloco la siguiente línea de código, ¿significa que estoy registrando fecha/hora al recibir el dato en el PC? ¿O está registrando cualquier otra hora? Estas líneas de código son:
`ahora = datetime.now()`
`fecha = ahora.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")`